# Android error during Post to PhpServer

Tags: php, android, json, insert

I'm trying to insert data using android to a PHP Server but i get an error. After i fill in the EditText. It goes to a page correctly but crashes. I always get the errors `java.lang.NullPointerExeption`and`org.json.JSONException`

Insert.class

```
class Insert extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Signup.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Creating User..");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * Creating product
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                String username = input_username.getText().toString();
                String password = input_password.getText().toString();

                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                // getting JSON Object
                // Note that create product url accepts POST method
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_signup, "POST", params);

                // check log cat fro response
                Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                // check for success tag
                try {
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully created product
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                        // closing this screen
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // failed to create product
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.print(e);
                }

                return null;
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog once done
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
```

Logcat

```
03-19 00:43:49.802: I/dalvikvm(1133): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getActivityLogo, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
03-19 00:43:49.802: W/dalvikvm(1133): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 371: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getActivityLogo (Landroid/content/ComponentName;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-19 00:43:49.812: D/dalvikvm(1133): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x008b
03-19 00:43:49.832: I/dalvikvm(1133): Could not find method android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.loadLogo, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
03-19 00:43:49.842: W/dalvikvm(1133): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 367: Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;.loadLogo (Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-19 00:43:49.842: D/dalvikvm(1133): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0099
03-19 00:43:49.902: D/dalvikvm(1133): VFY: dead code 0x008e-0092 in Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
03-19 00:43:49.902: D/dalvikvm(1133): VFY: dead code 0x009c-00a0 in Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
03-19 00:43:53.907: W/KeyCharacterMap(1133): No keyboard for id 0
03-19 00:43:53.907: W/KeyCharacterMap(1133): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
03-19 00:44:04.742: D/dalvikvm(1133): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4356 objects / 242400 bytes in 199ms
03-19 00:44:26.022: W/System.err(1133): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
03-19 00:44:26.042: W/System.err(1133):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocketImpl(Native Method)
03-19 00:44:26.042: W/System.err(1133):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocket(OSNetworkSystem.java:186)
03-19 00:44:26.066: W/System.err(1133):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:265)
03-19 00:44:26.066: W/System.err(1133):     at java.net.Socket.checkClosedAndCreate(Socket.java:873)
03-19 00:44:26.072: W/System.err(1133):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1020)
03-19 00:44:26.072: W/System.err(1133):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
03-19 00:44:26.072: W/System.err(1133):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
03-19 00:44:26.102: W/System.err(1133):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-19 00:44:26.102: W/System.err(1133):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-19 00:44:26.102: W/System.err(1133):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
03-19 00:44:26.102: W/System.err(1133):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-19 00:44:26.102: W/System.err(1133):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-19 00:44:26.112: W/System.err(1133):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-19 00:44:26.112: W/System.err(1133):     at com.example.signup.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:51)
03-19 00:44:26.112: W/System.err(1133):     at com.example.signup.Signup$Register.doInBackground(Signup.java:107)
03-19 00:44:26.112: W/System.err(1133):     at com.example.signup.Signup$Register.doInBackground(Signup.java:1)
03-19 00:44:26.112: W/System.err(1133):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-19 00:44:26.112: W/System.err(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-19 00:44:26.112: W/System.err(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-19 00:44:26.112: W/System.err(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-19 00:44:26.122: W/System.err(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-19 00:44:26.122: W/System.err(1133):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-19 00:44:26.122: E/Buffer Error(1133): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 00:44:26.122: E/JSON Parser(1133): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
03-19 00:44:26.142: W/dalvikvm(1133): threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-19 00:44:26.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-19 00:44:26.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-19 00:44:26.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
03-19 00:44:26.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-19 00:44:26.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-19 00:44:26.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-19 00:44:26.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-19 00:44:26.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-19 00:44:26.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-19 00:44:26.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-19 00:44:26.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 00:44:26.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at com.example.signup.Signup$Register.doInBackground(Signup.java:111)
03-19 00:44:26.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at com.example.signup.Signup$Register.doInBackground(Signup.java:1)
03-19 00:44:26.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-19 00:44:26.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-19 00:44:26.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     ... 4 more
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133): Activity com.example.signup.Signup has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43e665c0 that was originally added here
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.signup.Signup has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43e665c0 that was originally added here
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at com.example.signup.Signup$Register.onPreExecute(Signup.java:78)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at com.cit.cit_ueventcalendar.Signup$1.onClick(Signup.java:60)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-19 00:44:27.272: E/WindowManager(1133):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

signup.php

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES('$username', '$password')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: FYI your php code can be sql injected

Comment: Your app doesnt have permissions for internet for starters: `03-19 00:44:26.022: W/System.err(1133): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied`